# gitlab-ci does not recognize nvidia runtime

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, nvidia-docker

Deploying a container with docker-compose by using as `runtime: nvidia` to yml file,
gitlab-ci prompts with an error message

`ERROR: for container_name  Cannot create container for service worker: Unknown runtime specified nvidia`